# Lag Zero in VECM

Tags: r, vector-error-correction-model

I am trying to fit VECM model on my data. Data contains two non-stationary series of two Variables Y and X. I am trying to fit following VECM model using URCA package. Regressing Y on X and lagged variables of Y and X.

```
Model= ca.jo(twoK, K=2, type = "eigen", ecdet = "none",spec = "longrun")
```

Out put is following.

Response Y.d :

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y.d ~ ect1 + constant + Y.dl1 + X.dl1 - 1, data = data.mat)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.074320 -0.003940  0.000144  0.004299  0.049489 

Coefficients:
           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
ect1      0.0307250  0.0455352   0.675 0.499911    
constant  0.0008839  0.0009024   0.979 0.327467    
Y.dl1    -0.2631264  0.0656306  -4.009 6.32e-05 ***
X.dl1     0.2329280  0.0627615   3.711 0.000212 ***
```

output provides coefficients of First difference of Y and X at lag 1.

I wish to know how can I obtain coefficient of first difference of X at lag 0? I understand that first difference of Y at lag 0 doesn't make any sense as it is dependent variable. But, as per theory of Error correction model we should get coefficient of first difference of X at lag 0. This is basically coefficient to measure change in Y with respect to change in X.

Comment: If the futures price leads the spot price and does not error-correct towards it, you might just estimate this model (this single equation) with OLS; in R, you would create the relevant variables and use the `lm` function. But if the futures price error-corrects towards the spot price, then I do not know how you could estimate the equation. (As I mentioned, SVEC model could be used, but I am not proficient with it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the typical **reduced-form** (rather than **structural**) VEC model there **is no zero lag**. That is, contemporary value $\Delta x_t$ does not enter the equation for $\Delta y_t$ nor the other way around. The output you get from the `urca` package in R gives you the reduced-form estimates. For a structural VEC model, check out the vars package (vignette is [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf)).

There is a special case when you may estimate an equation with a zero lag directly, though. It is when $y$ error-corrects towards $x$ but $x$ does not error-correct towards $y$. Then $\Delta x_t$ is not endogenous in the equation for $\Delta y_t$ and you can estimate that equation directly by OLS.

Comment: Thanks... Would you know of Any other package that may provide me  contemporary value Δxt ? Where we can control number of lags as well.

Comment: @udayan, for a structural VEC model, check out the `vars` package (vignette is [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf)).

Comment: Hi Richard.... Still couldn't find a way to add contemporary value Δxt.  ECM package in R does provide functionality to add Δxt in model but it doesn't allow to add more than 1 Lag in ECM.   Please let me know if you come across any solution for this.... Will be of great help

Comment: @udayan, Why do you want to add the zero lag? If the data generating process is a VEC model with nonzero loadings on the error-correction term in both equations, you cannot really estimate contemporaneous effects because the variables are endogenous to each other.

Comment: @udayan, try adding the picture to your post. There should be a button at the top of the editor window allowing to include a picture.

Comment: Done... I am trying to find this beta in the equation. Relation between spot and futures

Comment: Saw ur reply....